# Could not initialize an installer - Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, torrent

I have been trying to install BitTorrent and µTorrent on my Macbook, and it's been 3 days I am unable to install it and error is **"Could not initialize a installer"**. I have searched multiple forums and applied whatever they were suggesting. Following is the screenshot attached I have been receiving.

[image]

[image]

What I have tried so far

- Tried the "JFX14" comment,

  1. Disable your Firewall by going to System Preferences>Security & Privacy. Click the Firewall tab then click the lock icon at the bottom of the window this will enable you to turn the Firewall on or off.
  2. Be sure you're not connected to a VPN or Proxy. < (I was able to install the latest uTorrent when I disconnected from my VPN).
     https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5818206

Comment: Please edit your post & let us know exactly what you did try, including links if appropriate.

Comment: The linked page doesn't show what you have tried, please include the specific steps you've done so far directly into the question.

Comment: So you are connecting to the Internet through a VPN? Are you sure that the VPN doesn't filter certain connections (including probably Torrents)?

Comment: i have tried with and without vpn.

Comment: My firewall is off but still facing issue after updating my OS to El Capitan.
I think the issue is in the El Capitan OS so if some one found any solution than please mention it....
thanks

Comment: did you try installing the beta version? explained here: https://nabtron.com/utorrent-not-installing-el-capitan-solved/

Comment: Nope, I stop the hunt after I found Transmission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I never got the answer, but I have found an alternative solution. 
I've used [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) for the Torrents.

Pros

- torent works, almost every torrent
- doesn't crash

Cons

- UI sucks

Answer (score 0):

Download a previous version of µTorrent. I had the same problem, downloaded 1.6.5. Works flawlessly.

Comment: Why isn't the new one working? Not only bittorrent even utorrent is causing the same error

Comment: Don't know but the previous version worked for me

Comment: Well i want to install the new version and and if it is happening to multiple users than there should be a solution or a remedy. Btw I tried the you said, but it is not working now.

Comment: I am still using yosemite though, so maybe its something with el capitan

Comment: Its is same on yosmite too. I have tried in yosmite as well thought it is something to yosmite, but it never worked on both

Comment: That's odd. Sorry man that's all I've got. Why don't you send u torrent an email, they might have a solution.

Comment: Dont know what to do but will try. Btw its bittorrent.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this link it will download utorrent 1.8.8 and should not come up with Could not initialize the installer

http://www.utorrent.com/intl/en/downloads/complete/os/osx/track/beta